# Why are fields which do not transform in a certain way not fundamental?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, vector-fields

When I was first exposed to Math physics textbooks and textbooks on vector calculus, I found:

1. Temperature distribution in a room $T(x,y,z,t)$ or the density variation in a fluid $\rho(x,y,z,t)$ etc were given as examples scalar fields.
2. The velocity field $\vec{v}(x,y,z,t)$ of a fluid stood as an example of a vector field.

But now I know that the examples above do not represent fundamental fields. This is because (I guess) they're only scalars and vectors under rotations but not under Lorentz transformations: neither the temperature field $T(x,y,z,t)$ nor the velocity field $\vec{v}(x,y,z,t)$ transform like a Lorentz scalar and Lorentz vector respectively. An example of the fundamental scalar field of nature is the Higgs field and that of a fundamental vector field is the $Z$-boson field.

But why a field must transform in a particular way under Lorentz transformation for it to be regarded as fundamental field of nature? I know that the nature is relativistic. But does that require the fundamental fields to behave in a certain way? How?

Comment: *the temperature field T(x,y,z,t)* [doesn't] *transform like a Lorentz scalar*. I'm not sure. How do you define temperature of a moving body? is there another way than to define it as the temperature measured in its rest frame?

Comment: @ElioFabri How do I find how $T$ transforms? No idea.

Comment: @ElioFabri I can find how the electric field transforms under Gallilen or Lorentz boost by considering the field due to a static point charge in one frame and the field in a frame moving w.r.t it. I think, likewise, I have to consider a particular temperature distribution produced by some source and boost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to the definitions of the words *fundamental* and *field*.

I would guess that you are taking the word *fundamental* to have the same meaning as in *fundamental particle*, in which case it specifically refers to one of the *quantum fields* in the Standard Model. These fields are necessarily Lorentz covariant because that's the way the Standard Model is constructed.

But this is a somewhat trivial statement since there are only seventeen such fields in the Standard model and the remaining $\infty - 17$ fields possible in the universe are then doomed to be consigned to the *non-fundamental* waste basket. It would make more sense to ask whether a field is Lorentz covariant or not and avoid the term fundamental. So for example a velocity field is not Lorentz covariant, though of course a four-velocity field is. There is nothing wrong with fields that are not Lorentz covariant as long as you're working in a regime where relativistic effects are negligible.

Comment: Is it a problem that all field (e.g., density field in my question) can not be quantised?